# Estimating an error term when counting primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

Let $f(x,p) = $ the number of integers $i$ where $0 < i \le x$ and lpf($i)>p$ where lpf($i)$ is the [least prime factor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastPrimeFactor.html) of $i$.

I believe that the exact answer is captured by this:

$$f(x,p) = \sum_{d | p\#}\mu(d)\left\lfloor\frac{x}{d}\right\rfloor$$

Unfortunately, the above equation is very hard to work with.

An approach that seems preferable is this:

$$f(x,p) = \left\lfloor\left(\prod_{q|p\#}\frac{q-1}{q}\right)x\right\rfloor - err(x)$$

where $err(x)$ is an error term.

Does this make sense for prime counting?  If so, what would be the standard way to estimate the upper bound of the error term?

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide an example of estimating the error term or provide a reference to an article where the error term is estimated.

Comment: *Halberstam - Sieve Methods* is the reference you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks!  I will check that out.

Comment: $p \#$ is the set of integers whose largest prime factor is $\le p$. Then $\sum_{d | p\#}\mu(d)\left\lfloor\frac{x}{d}\right\rfloor = x \prod_{q \le p} (1-\frac{1}{q})+\mathcal{O}(2^p)$

Comment: Fantastic!  Exactly what I was looking for!